# Finding L and R in AC circuit

Tags: ac, inductance, steady-state, voltmeter

[image: problem]

Ammeter readings:

A1 = 4A

A2 = 2A

A3 = 3A

Voltmeter reading 24V.
Circuit is in AC.
I have to find R1,R2 and L.

While calculating R1 (R1 = 24V/2A= 12 Ohm) seems to be easy, next steps are not particular clear to me. I know that ammeter measure magnitude of complex current, but I cannot utilise this fact.

edit: f=50Hz

Comment: Ahem, frequency needs to be specified then you can do it.

Comment: What do you mean, you cannot use the fact that an ammeter measures the magnitude of the current? How else are you supposed to interpret its reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint (or two): -

- Draw a triangle with sides of length 4, 3 and 2
- Each side represents the angle and magnitude of the currents relative to each other
- Calculate those angles using trig ([here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/reference/chpt-5/non-right-triangle-trigonometry/))
- The side that is length 2 is resistive (R1)

The angle of side "3" relative to angle of side "2" is due to the presence of the inductor in series with R2.

After that you are nearly there.

Comment: Okay, I've calculated value of A3 =(3∠75.5°)  and A1 = 4∠46.57°. But what should I do now? calculate: R2+jwL=24/(3∠75.5°)?

Comment: If the angles are relative to the current thru just the resistive path then yes.

Comment: Thanks to you I've managed to solve it:
http://i65.tinypic.com/2zdq7us.png
And to be sure: R1 = 12 Ohm, right?

Comment: @Antio R1 does equal 12 ohms and please feel free to mark this answer as accepted if you are still happy with it.